# Why don't DIMs reformat in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Is this another MS Access 2000(2007)-ism?

If I type the following:

```
foo =    blah + blah   - bar
```

the editor automatically reformats it as

```
foo = blah + blah - bar
```

But I type:

```
Dim foobar     as long
```

the editor doesn't reformat it at all. Some how I expect it to reformat it to

```
Dim foobar as long
```

Did it always work this way (I haven't got an older version to check against)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago I used to align the As in a list of Dims (in VB6)

```
Dim a    As Integer
Dim aa   As Integer
Dim abb  As Integer
Dim abcd As Integer
```

The arrival of .NET stopped me (thankfully).

Comment: I did that as well. Still sort of like it (note the "sort of"...).

Comment: I used to hate when I added a new variable with a longer name than previous vars and would have to have to realign everything.

Answer (score 2):

MS Access 2003 follows this behavior as well.  It could be that it doesn't reformat because of situations where users want to control length - like this:

```
Dim foobar        as long
Dim ID_10_T       as long
Dim realllly_long as long
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for years, but I seem to recall that behaviour yes.